# Supremum of $L^{2}$ norm is finite, show limit is integrable

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{ f_{n} \} \subset L^{2}(0,1)$ be such that $\sup_{n} || f_{n} ||_{2} < \infty$, and that $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere. 
 
a.) Show that $f \in L^{2}(0,1)$, 
b.) $\forall g \in L^{2}(0,1)$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \int_{0}^{1} f_{n} g = \int_{0}^{1} fg$. 
For $(a)$ what I think is that $|f_{n}|^{2} \rightarrow |f|^{2}$ almost everywhere. By Fatou's Lemma we have that $\int_{0}^{1} \liminf f_{n}(x) dx = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx \leq \liminf \int_{0}^{1} f_{n} = \liminf ||f_{n}||_{2} \leq \limsup ||f_{n}||_{2} \leq \sup_{n} ||f_{n}||_{2} < \infty$. This yields that $f \in L^{2}(0,1)$. Is this right? 
For $(b)$ I do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

a) should be done in this way, quite closed to your method:

\begin{align*}
\int|f|^{2}=\int\liminf_{n}|f_{n}|^{2}\leq\liminf_{n}\int|f_{n}|^{2}\leq\sup_{n}\|f\|_{L^{2}}^{2}<\infty.
\end{align*}

b) can be done in this way: 
Since $|g|^{2}\in L^{1}[0,1]$, for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that 
\begin{align*}
\int_{U}|g|^{2}<\epsilon,
\end{align*}
for all measurable set $U$ of $[0,1]$ with $|U|<\delta$

By Egorov, some measurable set $S\subseteq[0,1]$ is such that $|[0,1]-S|<\delta$ and that $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ uniformly in $S$, then
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}|f_{n}g-fg|&=\int_{S}|f_{n}-f||g|+\int_{[0,1]-S}|f_{n}-f||g|\\
&\leq\|f_{n}-f\|_{L^{2}(S)}\|g\|_{L^{2}[0,1]}+\|f_{n}-f\|_{L^{2}[0,1]}\|g\|_{L^{2}([0,1]-S)}\\
&\leq\|f_{n}-f\|_{L^{2}(S)}\|g\|_{L^{2}[0,1]}+\left(\sup_{n}\|f_{n}\|_{L^{2}[0,1]}+\|f\|_{L^{2}[0,1]}\right)\cdot\|g\|_{L^{2}([0,1]-S)}\\
&\leq\|f_{n}-f\|_{L^{2}(S)}\|g\|_{L^{2}[0,1]}+\left(\sup_{n}\|f_{n}\|_{L^{2}[0,1]}+\|f\|_{L^{2}[0,1]}\right)\cdot\epsilon^{1/2}.
\end{align*}
Since $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ uniformly in $S$, it is easy to see that $\|f_{n}-f\|_{L^{2}(S)}\rightarrow 0$, and hence
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n}\int_{0}^{1}|f_{n}g-fg|\leq\left(\sup_{n}\|f_{n}\|_{L^{2}[0,1]}+\|f\|_{L^{2}[0,1]}\right)\cdot\epsilon^{1/2}.
\end{align*}
The arbitrariness of $\epsilon>0$ gives 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n}\int_{0}^{1}|f_{n}g-fg|=0,
\end{align*}
which of course implies that
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}f_{n}g\rightarrow\int_{0}^{1}fg.
\end{align*}

Comment: How are you able to bound $\int_{0}^{1} |f_{n}g - fg| $ using $L^{2}$ norms. I would agree with the bounds if we were bounding $\int_{0}^{1} |f_{n}g - fg|^{2}$.

Comment: Holder's inequality with $2-2$ index.

Comment: So is the statement of holder's inequality $||fg||_{1} \leq ||f||_{p} ||g||_{q}$, and in this case we have $p = q= 2$?

Comment: Yes that was what I used.

Comment: Does it hold for arbitrary $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$? I see on Wikipedia it says that $1/p + 1/q = 1$. Is this a strict requirement?

Comment: Any positive $p,q$ such that $1/p+1/q=1$ will do, no natural numbers requirement.

Comment: Why do we even need to use Egorov's Theorem? Don't we have that $\int |f_{n}g - fg| = \int |f_{n} - f| \cdot |g| \leq ||f_{n}-f||_{2} \cdot ||g||_{2}$. Since $||g||_{2} < \infty$, and $||f_{n} - f||_{2} \rightarrow 0$, we have that $\int |f_{n}g-fg| \rightarrow 0$. Right?

Comment: There is no guarantee that $\|f_{n}-f\|_{L^{2}}\rightarrow 0$, this is the troubling issue we need to take extra care of.

Comment: So does uniform convergence imply $L^{2}$ convergence?

Comment: Only on finite domain, in this case, $[0,1]$. And also that $f$ need to be in $L^{2}$, which you have proved in the first question.